# Generating audio file from midi notes of various instruments

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, coremidi

I have a requirement where I need to play continuous midi sounds on user actions. I need to use only midi as I have a large set of instruments/sounds I need to play from. That is one part of the app which I was able to achieve. I used Audio graph etc for achieving that. Now the problem is with recording of those notes. As I mentioned I have many instruments, I need to record each instrument sound separately. So, I tried to save the midi note numbers into an array for each instrument. The problem now is I have to mix all of those sounds (ideally with out replaying them through a mixer) and create a music file out of them. One tedious way I could think of is to have each instrument recorded separately into a music file when the midi tone is played itself and finally mix all instrument music files by adding up. But the user may delay some instrument tunes etc and then, I am finding it pretty hard to mix. Also, I was unable to find a proper way with which I can mix audio files of various lengths, and delays before them. Can anyone please let me know if there is a way I can generate an audio file from the midi note numbers for various instruments without having to play them through the multi channel mixer and wait until the all the sounds are done playing through the mixer to record them? Please can you also let me know if you have a different approach with which this seems possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve but I'll take a shot.

If you were to use the Music Player API in Core Audio you could set up a Music Sequence with as many tracks as you need, one instrument per Music Track, and then write the midi data to each track as it occurs. That will give you a synced record of everything which was played. The sync is up to you: add the notes in real time (all tracks synced) or start adding notes at the beginning of each track.

Music Player will let you export a .midi file but you don't get the custom AUSampler sound fonts with that - so that's not really useful for you. I don't know of a way to generate an audio file without actually rendering it (playing it). Maybe a render callback on the mixer output - and the mixer not connected to remoteIO (don't know if that is possible).

Comment: Hi TOD, I will definitely try out the approach you pointed i.e rendering without connecting the mixer to remoteIO. Will keep you posted.